# Closing a Windows Background application with NSIS

Tags: windows, powershell, nsis

I am currently trying to close all running processes on a server as admin, including those running in the background. It works great with my shell, but not with NSIS.

Maybe someone can help me.

Thank you very much!

At the moment I am using the following code lines:

```
ExecWait "Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb runAs"
ExecWait 'powershell Stop-Process -Name "${EXE_NAME}" -Force -Tree -verb RunAs'
```

But this only closes the local process and not all of them.

Comment: In the meantime, I have also tested the nsProcess plug-in. The background process is also found here, but not closed.  However, there is also no error message about a missing authorization.   Maybe someone have a idea what to test next?